# When is the Flume memory channel not recoverable, and why?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, channel

I got confused how Flume data when using file-channel is recoverable and with memory channel is not.

I tried a Kafka sink, when i put Flume down while reading, Kafka reads the data (file) in channel properly. when Flume is restarted, the pipeline continue delivering data in reliable way. So how memory-channel is not recoverable?. In which case i need to recover data in channel?, specially if Flume starts reading the file from a saved offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart Kafka to check if the messages are lost.

Offset concept: 
This depends on the flume transaction handling. In the process of flume restart, some of the transactions might get committed, but the processing may fail due to connection loss. 
For eg: You have a transaction that requires some processing after which you store it in db. And you have transaction.commit() even when the flume sink throws any exception. So, you will loose your data in restart process as your processing logic throws exception. The transaction is committed and the offset is increased.

So it is safer to take an offset before restart process. You should follow

1. Take export offset
2. Stop flume
3. Import the offset
4. Start flume